# error 26 cannot connect to database

Tags: c#, database, linq

I took an old software made by someone else, which need to connect to a database with the .mdf extension.

But when I run the software, I have an `error 26`. I have obviously checked Google and it seems the the main problem is the firewall. But if I disable it the problem doesn't dissapear.

Here is the code for connect the database :

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\bddgestionvin.mdf");
```

I've noticed, when I try to connect the database with the datacontext class it fail too with the same `error 26`. (see attached screenshot below)

The string connection used by this class is :

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\bddgestionvin.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect `Timeout=30;User Instance=True`
```

I know I'm a little vague but I never did that kind of stuff (connect to a .mdf database) And the code is not mine, feel free the ask further explanation / code. Any help is welcome !

P.S The error message is

> SqlException was unhandled A network-related or instance-specific
> error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
> server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
> name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
> connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
> Locating Server/Instance Specified)

[image]

(Sorry for the french software)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to SQL Express "Error: 26-Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466974/unable-to-connect-to-sql-express-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-speci)

Comment: Is bddgestionvin.mdf in the execution app directory ? The sql connection says to auto attach mdf file in the app directory

Comment: Yes, he is in the bin/debug folder. And Yes I know there is plenty of topics about, but no one helped me, this is why I open a new topic

Comment: what's the issue getting? can you please update with message in engish.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I don't know you may see these steps. Make sure that these steps should pass.

> The reason that we get this error message is the client stack could
>   not receive SSRP response UDP packet from SQL Browser. It's easy to
>   isolate the issue. Here are the steps:
>
> 1) Make sure your server name is correct, e.g., no typo on the name.
>
> 2) Make sure your instance name is correct and there is actually such
>   an instance on your target machine. [Update: Some application converts
>   \ to . If you are not sure about your application, please try both
>   Server\Instance and Server\Instance in your connection string]
>
> 3) Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be resolve
>   correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always true).
>
> 4) Make sure SQL Browser service is running on the server.
>
> 5) If firewall is enabled on the server, you need to put
>   sqlbrowser.exe and/or UDP port 1434 into exception.

You can read more from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx)

You can also try [PortQry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832919) and validate your firewall does not block SQL Browser UDP packet

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.  `Failed to establish a connection with SQL Server.`

The server was not found or was not accessible. 
  `May be server is stopped, you don't have permission to access the server, or the instance name is not correct .`

Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

`Please goto SSMS and try connecting the server. Verify the SQL Server is running and your account is configured to access the service.`

(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Thanks

Comment: I'm running this software in a local stored database, do I need too check all that DNS / server steps?

Comment: from that image I can see that your are using './SQLEXPRESS'. Normally it means that the server will be localhost and the instance name is SQLEXPRESS. Is it possible for you to connect the SQL Server using SSMS ?

Comment: I don't know if I can connect using SSMS, I will take a look and give you news about it

Comment: Do you have SQL server installed in your local machine ?. Start->Run -> SSMS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189721.aspx

Comment: No, I don't have SQL Server, do I need to install it?

Comment: As per the picture, you are trying to connect a database server installed in your machine with the corresponding sql instance name `SQLEXPRESS`. I think you required sql server.