# SQL Server 2014 does not connect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have been working on SQL server 2014. It was working fine. Today when i was trying to connect to server it is not connecting. It is showing this error.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: hello, you connect your local server ???

Comment: ensure sql services / agents have started.. from the looks of it, it's a local machine.. check your services..

Comment: try this Q&A solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466974/unable-to-connect-to-sql-express-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-speci

Comment: just checked services and agents are running.

Comment: @ShumailaQamer please check my suggested link, that link contain all needed solutions for solve your problem, please try all solotion

Comment: Please google the error and make some effort at solving it yourself. This is a common error and there are many guides online to solving it

Answer (score 0):

This probably is the issue because Windows turn off some services to optimize the windows performance, You should Try this:

Search `Services` in your search bar and open it, Search for `SQL Server Services` from the list of services, right-click > start and try connecting to your SQL Server again. make sure they are running

[image]

Comment: Services are running i just checked

Comment: what authentication mode are you using? and if your server name is correct?

Comment: windows authentication, Server name verified too, it is also right.

Comment: My windows 10 just got updated, after updation it is not connecting

Comment: open your `cmd` and try to run this command there `net start` and see if SQL server shows up there

Comment: please try this `.\sqlexpress` as your server name and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

start MSSQLSERVER service from SERVICES tab in CONTROL PANEL
provided you are typing right database credentials

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might want to start SQL server using SQL server configuration Manager (you can find it directly from Start menu) or you can go to the path in your C Drive based on SQL server version

See link from Microsoft:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017