# How to fix " A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server" error in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, plesk

I published my site on plesk, in login form when I enter username and password I get error. I should say that my login form is based on asp.net configuration and roles and users are set there.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
>   sqlAuthProviderManager) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at
>   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context,
>   Boolean revertImpersonate) at
>   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String
>   connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) at
>   System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
>   at System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(String username) at
>   RealEstate.login.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\EZ-TECH\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\3Layer\RealEstate\RealEstate\login.aspx.cs:line 36
>   ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Error
>   Number:-1,State:0,Class:20

Comment: Have you updated the database connection string for connecting to server database?

Comment: yes I have a connectionstring in my web.config

Comment: Verify that connection string is correct and you are able to connect to sql server instance using the credentials provided in connection string. Note that mostly you have to update connection string when application is published on the set server

Comment: Have you read [Unable to connect to SQL Express "Error: 26-Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466974/unable-to-connect-to-sql-express-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-speci)?

Comment: If you've used that string for a while, double check that the credentials for that user didn't expire in sql server.

Answer (score 3):

I had same error, I later figured out that I was using a forward slash (`/`) instead of backslash (`\`) slash in my connection string.

This was what I was using-:

```
Server=(localdb)//mssqllocaldb;
```

While this was the correct connection string:

```
Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was intermmitent error, on and off. It was caused by DB server having IP conflict. Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several issues causing your error:

**1)** Make sure your server name is correct, e.g., no typo on the name.

**2)** Make sure your instance name is correct and there is actually such an instance on your target machine. [Update: Some application converts \ to . If you are not sure about your application, please try both ServerInstance and Server\Instance in your connection string]

**3)** Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be resolve correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always true). Simply open Command Prompt and type "-ping yourservername" if it is a named instance or "-ping yourserverIP" if it is an unnamed instance.

**4)** Make sure SQL Browser service is running on the server.

**5)** If firewall is enabled on the server, you need to put sqlbrowser.exe and/or UDP port 1434 into exception.

I had the same issue with an application of mine and it was resolved by **4)**, enabling the SQL Browsing service on the server.

Reference and additional information: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serverinstance-specified/

Answer (score 0):

*Localhost Sql server
*Database name is sample
*connectionString name is SampleConnectinString

- Just check for connection string, your error will go

---

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="SampleConnectinString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog= sample;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

---

*using connectionstring in ado.net

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleConnectinString"].ConnectionString;SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
```

Answer (score 0):

the connection string might be the problem.check once whether you were able to login in sql server in your pc with the connection mentioned in config file.
FYI:IIf yusing go daddy as host remove the name after colon in host.
eg:host=198.71.225.113:1433
use only "data source=198.71.225.113" ignore ":1433"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use Data source="localhost\SQLEXPRESS" instead of Data source=".\SQLEXPRESS"